# Elm updating model from json response

Tags: json, elm

I am having an issue with updating a model from a JSON response through one of my actions.
Here is the setup:

I have models that looks like this:

```
type alias Model =
  { totals: Totals.Total // all values are initialized as 0 or 0.0
  }

-- In other module

type alias Total =
  { days : Int
  , avgPerDay: Float
  , reports : Int
  , people : Int
  , locations : Int
  , totalCoffees : Int
  , coffeesPerDay: Float
  }
```

A decoder for said model:

```
decodeTotal : Json.Decoder Total
decodeTotal =
  object7 Total
      ("days" := Json.int)
      ("avgPerDay" := Json.float)
      ("reports" := Json.int)
      ("people" := Json.int)
      ("locations" := Json.int)
      ("totalCoffees" := Json.int)
      ("coffeesPerDay" := Json.float)
```

To update the model, the following Http request is called:

```
getTotals : Effects Action
getTotals =
  Http.get Totals.decodeTotal ("/reports/totals")
    |> Task.toMaybe
    |> Task.map TotalsFetched
    |> Effects.task
```

The response from the server is 200 OK with this body:   `{"days":347,"reports":1793,"avgPerDay":5.167147,"people":205,"locations":332,"coffees":146,"coffeesPerDay":0.42074928}`

However, in the `TotalsFetched` Action:

```
update : Action -> Model -> (Model, Effects Action)
update action model =
  case action of
    TotalsFetched totals ->
      log (toString totals)  -- logs Nothing
      ( { model | totals = Maybe.withDefault model.totals totals }
      , Effects.none
      )
```

I am assuming that since `totals` is `Nothing` my model just stays as is described in the `Maybe.withDefault`

I don't understand why `totals` is Nothing instead of the Decoded response from the server. This is my first elm project, so I wouldn't be surprised if I am missing something really obvious to the trained eye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is returning a field called `coffees` while your decoder is looking for `totalCoffees`.

You may want to consider using [`Task.toResult`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Task#toResult) instead of `Task.toMaybe` because that way you'll get an error message returned when something goes wrong.

Comment: That was it. Thanks for noticing the tiny error and the suggestion to use `Task.toResult`. The silent failure made this hard to reason about.